Implementing a DMN for IP plan matching - How to use a FEEEL expresion to match CIDIR aginst an IP to set a name
The Goal
The goal is to run a list of devices with an IP though an Decision Table in DMN, to identify which naming convention to use for the devices based on an IP Plan using CIDIR to select which naming pattern to use.
Expectations

Fix the compile error: It seems like, that the problem is the bitwise comparing. I know, that it could properly implement the logic in another language, but as I'm trying hard to keep neutral for which DMN implementation it will run on. Ideas of how to implement the CIDR match differently in FEEL, whould be great.
Run a list of tDevices though the DMN getting a list of tIPPlanLine with a given name pattern, for use in later processes.

Current solution design
The DMN consist of a BKM (Business Knowledge Model) with a FEEL function, which matches a IP against a CIDIR and return a boolean and a Decision Table which uses the FEEL function.
Using the given data types:

tDevice (Structure)

ip (string)
mac (string)
vendor (string)
match (boolean) //This is just a dummy place holder, to have the match check


tIPPlanLine (Structure)

cidrIP (string)
prefixLength (string)
namePattern (string)


tIPSegments (Number) list


Using the given function CIDRvalidator (boolean) which takes the following input:

ip (string)
cidrIp (string)
prefixLength (number)

It runs the following FEEL function, which uses Context to store temporal values



F
CIDRvalidator (boolean)





F
(ip:(string), cidrIp:(string), prefixLength: (string))



1
Context{}



1
splitIp (tIPSegment)
[for part in split(ip, ".") return number(part)]


1
splitCidrIp (tIPSegment)
[for part in split(cidrIp, ".") return number(part)]


1
ipBits(number)
splitIp[1] * 2**24 + splitIp[2] * 2**16 + splitIp[3] * 2**8 + splitIp[4]


1
cidrBits(number)
splitCidrIp[1] * 2**24 + splitCidrIp[2] * 2**16 + splitCidrIp[3] * 2**8 + splitCidrIp[4]


1
mask(number)
(2**prefixLength - 1) * 2**(32 - prefixLength)


1
<result>
(ipBits & mask) = (cidrBits & mask)



Then, I'm trying to use this function in a Decision Table that takes a tDevice (Structure) as input and produces a tIPPlanLine as output. I have tried various ways of creating the Decision table to make it use the function and use the cidrIp and prefixLength to select the name.
Attempts to build the Decision Table
First Attempt
(The "match" attribute was not part of the tDevice)



(input) Device.ip
(input) Device.mac
(input) Device.vendor
(input) CIDRvalidator(Device.ip, cidrIp, prefixLength)
(output) cidr
(output) prefixLength
(output) namePattern




-
-
-
true
192.168.1.1
24
namepattern1


-
-
-
true
192.168.2.1
24
namepattern2



Issue: It duplicates the input line.
Second Attempt
(The "match" attribute was added the tDevice)



(input) Device.ip
(input) Device.mac
(input) Device.vendor
(input) match
(output) cidr
(output) prefixLength
(output) namePattern




-
-
-
CIDRvalidator(Device.ip, cidrIp, prefixLength)
192.168.1.1
24
"namepattern1"


-
-
-
CIDRvalidator(Device.ip, cidrIp, prefixLength)
192.168.2.1
24
"namepattern2"



Issue: It duplicates the input line.
Third Attempt
(The "cidrIp" and "prefixLength" attribute from the out was replace with the values of them, to make the lines unique (it subuptimale to dublicate the values))



(input) Device.ip
(input) Device.mac
(input) Device.vendor
(input) match
(output) cidr
(output) prefixLength
(output) namePattern




-
-
-
CIDRvalidator(Device.ip, "192.168.1.1", 24)
192.168.1.1
24
"namepattern1"


-
-
-
CIDRvalidator(Device.ip, "192.168.2.1", 24)
192.168.2.1
24
"namepattern2"



Issue: The FEEL expression has a syntax error.
[ERROR] Error compiling FEEL expression '(ipBits & mask) = (cidrBits & mask)' for name 'CIDRvalidator' on node 'CIDRvalidator': syntax error near '&'

Current State of the DMN
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dmn:definitions xmlns:dmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20180521/MODEL/" xmlns="https://kiegroup.org/dmn/_8213A7EA-FB3C-4323-8E45-D1AE2F2CDCB3" xmlns:feel="http://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20180521/FEEL/" xmlns:kie="http://www.drools.org/kie/dmn/1.2" xmlns:dmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20180521/DMNDI/" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20180521/DI/" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20180521/DC/" id="_80BEA9F1-0F0C-4FBC-ABBB-8A4F66A10B9C" name="ip_plan" typeLanguage="http://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20180521/FEEL/" namespace="https://kiegroup.org/dmn/_8213A7EA-FB3C-4323-8E45-D1AE2F2CDCB3">
  <dmn:extensionElements/>
  <dmn:itemDefinition id="_DDC31CD8-7CB4-4993-B0EE-85131DFDA7C4" name="tDevice" isCollection="false">
    <dmn:itemComponent id="_3EFAF0CF-6490-4F55-A40C-DF47AB112388" name="ip" isCollection="false">
      <dmn:typeRef>string</dmn:typeRef>
    </dmn:itemComponent>
    <dmn:itemComponent id="_A77DC46A-B52A-4A69-9FE7-BBA7C2014578" name="mac" isCollection="false">
      <dmn:typeRef>string</dmn:typeRef>
    </dmn:itemComponent>
    <dmn:itemComponent id="_ECCE017F-FB81-4D39-83D5-490798BDC7E8" name="vendor" isCollection="false">
      <dmn:typeRef>string</dmn:typeRef>
    </dmn:itemComponent>
    <dmn:itemComponent id="_5775B59C-D190-474A-9E72-0E810F658685" name="match" isCollection="false">
      <dmn:typeRef>boolean</dmn:typeRef>
    </dmn:itemComponent>
  </dmn:itemDefinition>
  <dmn:itemDefinition id="_CBF7CF1B-DAC1-41FE-9B44-B3AFBCFBA553" name="tIPPlanLine" isCollection="false">
    <dmn:itemComponent id="_56B199F3-BB24-4E7A-B6A0-FE944867B950" name="cidrIP" isCollection="false">
      <dmn:typeRef>string</dmn:typeRef>
    </dmn:itemComponent>
    <dmn:itemComponent id="_5B3A06F6-FEF9-411D-9D5C-CB8DACB9CE46" name="prefixLength" isCollection="false">
      <dmn:typeRef>string</dmn:typeRef>
    </dmn:itemComponent>
    <dmn:itemComponent id="_B7A96201-879B-4EEE-9244-8198CF085C64" name="namePattern" isCollection="false">
      <dmn:typeRef>string</dmn:typeRef>
    </dmn:itemComponent>
  </dmn:itemDefinition>
  <dmn:itemDefinition id="_CFE6F064-C8FE-42C8-878D-84B72A05F972" name="tIPSegments" isCollection="true">
    <dmn:typeRef>number</dmn:typeRef>
  </dmn:itemDefinition>
  <dmn:inputData id="_19F5D0A7-D55D-4E17-9BAE-7359B0C2FE21" name="Device">
    <dmn:extensionElements/>
    <dmn:variable id="_F7A74B32-C449-4F80-A879-3D65722C3CC3" name="Device" typeRef="tDevice"/>
  </dmn:inputData>
  <dmn:decision id="_E0CF4F27-2184-4C01-BE0B-314EDCE8441D" name="IPplanLine">
    <dmn:extensionElements/>
    <dmn:variable id="_DE1B32F5-F93F-4341-9D6D-B087E16755A4" name="IPplanLine" typeRef="tIPPlanLine"/>
    <dmn:informationRequirement id="_DE116BF0-FC7D-4AEC-AAC0-BE2D67EACC41">
      <dmn:requiredInput href="#_19F5D0A7-D55D-4E17-9BAE-7359B0C2FE21"/>
    </dmn:informationRequirement>
    <dmn:knowledgeRequirement id="_AEB52860-B199-438A-9A34-C59A08B28ECC">
      <dmn:requiredKnowledge href="#_6FE98E04-586E-46D3-BB1D-E2E2FB305791"/>
    </dmn:knowledgeRequirement>
    <dmn:decisionTable id="_9059DF09-BB5D-4B93-85E8-98666481B9CA" hitPolicy="FIRST" preferredOrientation="Rule-as-Row">
      <dmn:input id="_8D618DA3-4BC1-4C77-AB95-6B0C43B32DA6">
        <dmn:inputExpression id="_743D7EBE-2B2B-4EE5-B4DE-33D1D241D0EE">
          <dmn:text>Device.ip</dmn:text>
        </dmn:inputExpression>
      </dmn:input>
      <dmn:input id="_A5E17F4F-5A87-489B-AE41-59DD69581B4D">
        <dmn:inputExpression id="_B19A149E-4257-4656-BD00-90935F09E16B" typeRef="string">
          <dmn:text>Device.mac</dmn:text>
        </dmn:inputExpression>
      </dmn:input>
      <dmn:input id="_1CC9B798-BDC2-44E2-AE95-1D34F0D3A2CF">
        <dmn:inputExpression id="_4ADA3384-F73A-471E-8F24-2AFAD6904AD4" typeRef="string">
          <dmn:text>Device.vendor</dmn:text>
        </dmn:inputExpression>
      </dmn:input>
      <dmn:input id="_4DAF1A7A-6330-4388-B49F-A45DF96D16AD">
        <dmn:inputExpression id="_8530615F-DA05-468F-A3A8-7A108014BD46" typeRef="boolean">
          <dmn:text>Device.match</dmn:text>
        </dmn:inputExpression>
      </dmn:input>
      <dmn:output id="_DDCAFA4F-7756-41A1-860D-6A1DD21B0F3E" name="cidrIP" typeRef="string"/>
      <dmn:output id="_723BE867-D081-4B7F-AB86-AFE4BB176A90" name="namePattern" typeRef="string"/>
      <dmn:output id="_7C5554BD-C2D8-4DDB-9194-3D5B39A2136D" name="prefixLength" typeRef="number"/>
      <dmn:annotation name="annotation-1"/>
      <dmn:rule id="_B874FE75-6478-4F28-9FE0-88FB601B41E2">
        <dmn:inputEntry id="_ED696F9F-6E9D-48A0-8905-E01857B05868">
          <dmn:text>-</dmn:text>
        </dmn:inputEntry>
        <dmn:inputEntry id="_BC1C6BE6-63CA-480A-8155-81B2BACCE39C">
          <dmn:text>-</dmn:text>
        </dmn:inputEntry>
        <dmn:inputEntry id="_AB4F5322-734F-4C93-9AF0-829151AD1587">
          <dmn:text>-</dmn:text>
        </dmn:inputEntry>
        <dmn:inputEntry id="_68947F2A-D021-4DC4-8F78-7BBFD20DF3DF">
          <dmn:text>CIDRvalidator(Device.ip,"10.56.11.222",24)</dmn:text>
        </dmn:inputEntry>
        <dmn:outputEntry id="_E592BEDC-24F0-4A48-9AA5-41D9562F9A26">
          <dmn:text>"10.56.11.222"</dmn:text>
        </dmn:outputEntry>
        <dmn:outputEntry id="_F710DBFE-255D-4A15-B82E-AAE132A5CB2C">
          <dmn:text>"name1"</dmn:text>
        </dmn:outputEntry>
        <dmn:outputEntry id="_5F9C9052-4146-479D-86BC-E86732F6AEE4">
          <dmn:text>24</dmn:text>
        </dmn:outputEntry>
        <dmn:annotationEntry>
          <dmn:text/>
        </dmn:annotationEntry>
      </dmn:rule>
      <dmn:rule id="_61F5698F-EBDE-4AB1-9C97-C572A46A645D">
        <dmn:inputEntry id="_AC6CCC25-2DAA-4F27-B005-A392C03B3D69">
          <dmn:text>-</dmn:text>
        </dmn:inputEntry>
        <dmn:inputEntry id="_3469243A-E23E-402C-B14B-8E9186B1F97B">
          <dmn:text>-</dmn:text>
        </dmn:inputEntry>
        <dmn:inputEntry id="_FAA65F8D-ADD1-4399-9629-537BB7624572">
          <dmn:text>-</dmn:text>
        </dmn:inputEntry>
        <dmn:inputEntry id="_6E5A1053-411D-448F-BB4D-D91141415642">
          <dmn:text>CIDRvalidator(Device.ip,"10.56.21.8",24)</dmn:text>
        </dmn:inputEntry>
        <dmn:outputEntry id="_351FEF01-D875-4F6B-A01C-229E4B6A4F93">
          <dmn:text>"10.56.21.8"</dmn:text>
        </dmn:outputEntry>
        <dmn:outputEntry id="_CDB14B6F-C537-4784-AF6E-4ECF9C4A4485">
          <dmn:text>"name2"</dmn:text>
        </dmn:outputEntry>
        <dmn:outputEntry id="_691324BE-A9DB-48B7-9568-0AB91283CFA2">
          <dmn:text>24</dmn:text>
        </dmn:outputEntry>
        <dmn:annotationEntry>
          <dmn:text/>
        </dmn:annotationEntry>
      </dmn:rule>
    </dmn:decisionTable>
  </dmn:decision>
  <dmn:businessKnowledgeModel id="_6FE98E04-586E-46D3-BB1D-E2E2FB305791" name="CIDRvalidator">
    <dmn:extensionElements/>
    <dmn:variable id="_2B2A3D19-C45E-4EAD-8DC0-D81BA1D183D3" name="CIDRvalidator" typeRef="boolean"/>
    <dmn:encapsulatedLogic id="_6307CC06-C3AC-4A34-B833-E81C7721D0D5" kind="FEEL">
      <dmn:formalParameter id="_A8442321-71DB-4142-A8AD-75D1859C649F" name="ip" typeRef="string"/>
      <dmn:formalParameter id="_6904C2A7-7BF2-4F00-B74D-FB46E2F95D8D" name="cidrIp" typeRef="string"/>
      <dmn:formalParameter id="_F5A37C49-D10C-4BC5-B8A1-71E3D5849EFB" name="prefixLength" typeRef="number"/>
      <dmn:context id="_957FE2BD-70DE-4762-AC21-C998ADB67341">
        <dmn:contextEntry>
          <dmn:variable id="_8DA684EA-CA55-46E3-8774-0D8A1A0E16FD" name="splitIp" typeRef="tIPSegments">
            <dmn:description>Split IP address into numerical parts</dmn:description>
          </dmn:variable>
          <dmn:literalExpression id="_972AACD9-3443-48E2-8697-AF20FD4DBFB5">
            <dmn:text>[for part in split(ip, ".") return number(part)]</dmn:text>
          </dmn:literalExpression>
        </dmn:contextEntry>
        <dmn:contextEntry>
          <dmn:variable id="_ADA7E3AC-0E7B-42DB-BD80-6387F9E8CAB9" name="splitCidrIp" typeRef="tIPSegments">
            <dmn:description>Split CIDR IP address into numerical parts</dmn:description>
          </dmn:variable>
          <dmn:literalExpression id="_20CA00E3-9838-41E9-985E-CEBA4C5FC035">
            <dmn:text>[for part in split(cidrIp, ".") return number(part)]</dmn:text>
          </dmn:literalExpression>
        </dmn:contextEntry>
        <dmn:contextEntry>
          <dmn:variable id="_AB3A623E-342B-48CA-98AC-1355F5ACAA25" name="ipBits" typeRef="number">
            <dmn:description>Convert split parts to IP bits</dmn:description>
          </dmn:variable>
          <dmn:literalExpression id="_C9CE7B83-E441-47C9-AE35-BD8786EC19BA">
            <dmn:text>splitIp[1] * 2**24 + splitIp[2] * 2**16 + splitIp[3] * 2**8 + splitIp[4]</dmn:text>
          </dmn:literalExpression>
        </dmn:contextEntry>
        <dmn:contextEntry>
          <dmn:variable id="_D072192F-95B4-4C17-89B8-7DD24EACDC1F" name="cidrBits" typeRef="number">
            <dmn:description>Convert split parts to CIDR IP bits</dmn:description>
          </dmn:variable>
          <dmn:literalExpression id="_1B107F0B-22CD-4FF3-818B-73DF7C138C92">
            <dmn:text>splitCidrIp[1] * 2**24 + splitCidrIp[2] * 2**16 + splitCidrIp[3] * 2**8 + splitCidrIp[4]</dmn:text>
          </dmn:literalExpression>
        </dmn:contextEntry>
        <dmn:contextEntry>
          <dmn:variable id="_60A2DE4A-29E0-4815-80DD-64AF0B948B24" name="mask" typeRef="number">
            <dmn:description>Generate mask</dmn:description>
          </dmn:variable>
          <dmn:literalExpression id="_8F50D5B8-1444-4C89-9DDA-E63ABC0D7DD4">
            <dmn:text>(2**prefixLength - 1) * 2**(32 - prefixLength)</dmn:text>
          </dmn:literalExpression>
        </dmn:contextEntry>
        <dmn:contextEntry>
          <dmn:literalExpression id="_B3CEE1BC-E004-457E-B200-28A60280D229">
            <dmn:text>(ipBits &amp; mask) = (cidrBits &amp; mask)</dmn:text>
          </dmn:literalExpression>
        </dmn:contextEntry>
      </dmn:context>
    </dmn:encapsulatedLogic>
  </dmn:businessKnowledgeModel>
  <dmndi:DMNDI>
    <dmndi:DMNDiagram id="_65E29651-CE18-4371-A45A-323DE635E4B9" name="DRG">
      <di:extension>
        <kie:ComponentsWidthsExtension>
          <kie:ComponentWidths dmnElementRef="_9059DF09-BB5D-4B93-85E8-98666481B9CA">
            <kie:width>50</kie:width>
            <kie:width>100</kie:width>
            <kie:width>100</kie:width>
            <kie:width>100</kie:width>
            <kie:width>286</kie:width>
            <kie:width>100</kie:width>
            <kie:width>100</kie:width>
            <kie:width>100</kie:width>
            <kie:width>100</kie:width>
          </kie:ComponentWidths>
          <kie:ComponentWidths dmnElementRef="_957FE2BD-70DE-4762-AC21-C998ADB67341">
            <kie:width>50</kie:width>
            <kie:width>120</kie:width>
            <kie:width>279</kie:width>
          </kie:ComponentWidths>
          <kie:ComponentWidths dmnElementRef="_972AACD9-3443-48E2-8697-AF20FD4DBFB5">
            <kie:width>279</kie:width>
          </kie:ComponentWidths>
          <kie:ComponentWidths dmnElementRef="_20CA00E3-9838-41E9-985E-CEBA4C5FC035">
            <kie:width>279</kie:width>
          </kie:ComponentWidths>
          <kie:ComponentWidths dmnElementRef="_C9CE7B83-E441-47C9-AE35-BD8786EC19BA">
            <kie:width>279</kie:width>
          </kie:ComponentWidths>
          <kie:ComponentWidths dmnElementRef="_1B107F0B-22CD-4FF3-818B-73DF7C138C92">
            <kie:width>279</kie:width>
          </kie:ComponentWidths>
          <kie:ComponentWidths dmnElementRef="_8F50D5B8-1444-4C89-9DDA-E63ABC0D7DD4">
            <kie:width>279</kie:width>
          </kie:ComponentWidths>
          <kie:ComponentWidths dmnElementRef="_B3CEE1BC-E004-457E-B200-28A60280D229">
            <kie:width>279</kie:width>
          </kie:ComponentWidths>
          <kie:ComponentWidths dmnElementRef="_6307CC06-C3AC-4A34-B833-E81C7721D0D5">
            <kie:width>50</kie:width>
            <kie:width>469</kie:width>
          </kie:ComponentWidths>
        </kie:ComponentsWidthsExtension>
      </di:extension>
      <dmndi:DMNShape id="dmnshape-drg-_19F5D0A7-D55D-4E17-9BAE-7359B0C2FE21" dmnElementRef="_19F5D0A7-D55D-4E17-9BAE-7359B0C2FE21" isCollapsed="false">
        <dmndi:DMNStyle>
          <dmndi:FillColor red="255" green="255" blue="255"/>
          <dmndi:StrokeColor red="0" green="0" blue="0"/>
          <dmndi:FontColor red="0" green="0" blue="0"/>
        </dmndi:DMNStyle>
        <dc:Bounds x="550" y="172" width="100" height="50"/>
        <dmndi:DMNLabel/>
      </dmndi:DMNShape>
      <dmndi:DMNShape id="dmnshape-drg-_E0CF4F27-2184-4C01-BE0B-314EDCE8441D" dmnElementRef="_E0CF4F27-2184-4C01-BE0B-314EDCE8441D" isCollapsed="false">
        <dmndi:DMNStyle>
          <dmndi:FillColor red="255" green="255" blue="255"/>
          <dmndi:StrokeColor red="0" green="0" blue="0"/>
          <dmndi:FontColor red="0" green="0" blue="0"/>
        </dmndi:DMNStyle>
        <dc:Bounds x="378" y="304" width="100" height="50"/>
        <dmndi:DMNLabel/>
      </dmndi:DMNShape>
      <dmndi:DMNShape id="dmnshape-drg-_6FE98E04-586E-46D3-BB1D-E2E2FB305791" dmnElementRef="_6FE98E04-586E-46D3-BB1D-E2E2FB305791" isCollapsed="false">
        <dmndi:DMNStyle>
          <dmndi:FillColor red="255" green="255" blue="255"/>
          <dmndi:StrokeColor red="0" green="0" blue="0"/>
          <dmndi:FontColor red="0" green="0" blue="0"/>
        </dmndi:DMNStyle>
        <dc:Bounds x="204" y="402" width="100" height="50"/>
        <dmndi:DMNLabel/>
      </dmndi:DMNShape>
      <dmndi:DMNEdge id="dmnedge-drg-_DE116BF0-FC7D-4AEC-AAC0-BE2D67EACC41-AUTO-SOURCE-AUTO-TARGET" dmnElementRef="_DE116BF0-FC7D-4AEC-AAC0-BE2D67EACC41">
        <di:waypoint x="600" y="172"/>
        <di:waypoint x="428" y="354"/>
      </dmndi:DMNEdge>
      <dmndi:DMNEdge id="dmnedge-drg-_AEB52860-B199-438A-9A34-C59A08B28ECC" dmnElementRef="_AEB52860-B199-438A-9A34-C59A08B28ECC">
        <di:waypoint x="254" y="427"/>
        <di:waypoint x="428" y="354"/>
      </dmndi:DMNEdge>
    </dmndi:DMNDiagram>
    <dmndi:DMNDiagram id="_C026D2CA-057A-41BB-B495-BF3503771880" name="new-diagram">
      <di:extension>
        <kie:ComponentsWidthsExtension/>
      </di:extension>
    </dmndi:DMNDiagram>
  </dmndi:DMNDI>
</dmn:definitions>


Hi, as you wrote the problem is the bitwise operator probably. The only alternative I have in mind is to introduce a separate BKM Node (BitwiseOperatorHelper for example) that would be defined as java function. So It can point to java class of your project, more precisely to a static java method of your project. This method can take single parameter. So instead of bitwiseMethod(int a, int b) it needs to bitwiseMethod(int[] operators) and you need to parse a and b as part of bitwiseMethod body.


Fix the compile error: It seems like, that the problem is the bitwise comparing.


Issue: The FEEL expression has a syntax error.
[ERROR] Error compiling FEEL expression '(ipBits & mask) = (cidrBits & mask)' for name 'CIDRvalidator' on node 'CIDRvalidator': syntax error near '&'

DMN Specification v1.5, I can't see any mention of bitwise operation.
So, using number & number looks to me is not a valid FEEL syntax.
As @jomarko mentioned in the comment, the pragmatic approach here would be to delegate this to a BKM making an external call. (or implementing the bitwise operator in FEEL as a custom function).
